# How to share video / audio file on facebook from iPhone app created using titanium appcelrator

Tags: javascript, iphone, facebook, titanium, sharing

I want to share video / audio any kind of file on Facebook .
I am able share status or other all stuffs except audio / video.i am working in titanium . here is my code

```
login.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    Titanium.Facebook.authorize();
    var f=Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory+"/"+"audio"+"/"+"abc.mp4");
   var blob=f.nativePath;
   alert(blob);
  var data={
    message: 'Check this video!',    
    video: blob
   }

  Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('me/videos', data, 'POST', function(e) {
        if (e.success) 
          {
               alert("Success!  From FB: " + e.result);

            } else if (e.error) {
                alert(e.error);
            } else {
                alert('Unknown response.');
            }
    });  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only passing the file path (`nativePath`) to Facebook, instead try passing the actual image blob like this:

```
var blob=f.read();
var data={
    message: 'Check this video!',    
    video: blob
}
// The rest....
```

Comment: hey Josiah Hester,  i have tried with f.read() and also i have given hard-coded path to data   but still it won't works..

Answer (score 0):

## Here is the answer #

```
            var url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos";
            Titanium.Facebook.authorize();
            var xhr_video = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

            xhr_video.open('POST', url);

            xhr_video.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');

            xhr_video.onload = function(e) {

                alert("Video Has Been Successfully Posted to Your Timeline");

            };
            xhr_video.onerror = function(e) {
                alert(e);
                xhr_video.abort();

            };
            var f=Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory+"/"+"audio"+"/"+"video.mp4");
              var blob=f.read();
            var data = {
                video : blob,
                //access_token : Titanium.Facebook.getAccessToken()
                access_token:Ti.Facebook.accessToken
            };
            alert(data);
            xhr_video.send(data);
```